# What's it called for a heatmap with things that aren't square and test points are all over it?

Tags: data-visualization, heatmap

I'm trying to make a visualization of my home states' temperature ranges, but I'm not sure what the name of the plot I want is called. It's like a heatmap, but the test points with a value are located all over the place, and it's not a grid, it's more like a interpolation between the points for the colors.

Each of the points plotted so far have a weight associated with them, and I want to shade the differences between them.

Here's what I have so far:
[image]

Comment: I'd still call that a heat map. If you do a google image search for 'heat map', you'll find many plots similar to what you're describing.

Comment: Are you looking for a "contour plot", as in https://plot.ly/pandas/contour-plots/ ?